# difference between printf and println in java?

Tags: java, printf, println

Just came to know that `java` does has a method named `printf`, then what is the difference between `printf` & `println`?

Comment: `printf` is like the C `printf` function, "print format", the other is a more (or less) updated version, which doesn't require a format and value list...What does the JavaDoc's tell you?

Comment: @MadProgrammer than what is the use of it if we have `format` and `printf` the same ?

Comment: Because for many, `printf` is confusing and be difficult to use if you've not used it before.  You can use `println("Say " + word)` or `printf("Say %s%n", word)`, which one is generally more easier to read?  C doesn't have a `String` in the sense that Java does, so allowing `println` simplifies the process

Comment: @shikjohari kindly read the question properly as it's about difference and not about which one is better and I had gone through your mentioned before posting this question.

Comment: @BhargavModi Well if you go through the answer of that question, you ll understand why I said this as a dupclicate. Read the asnwers also properly :)

Comment: The difference is not very important since both should be avoided. It's better to use a logger to output your text. And if you need your logged text to be formatted, use `String.format`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.out.println();` is efficient for simply printing a line of text. If the line of text needs to be formatted (ex: alignment (left-justified, etc.), etc.), then `System.out.printf();` would be used.

Check out [this link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more information.