# what is the syntax to print a integer in java

Tags: java, printing, syntax

In c language,a integer can be printed as follows.

```
    int a=5; 
    printf("%d",a);
```

My question is how does these above lines can be written in java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between printf and println in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758636/difference-between-printf-and-println-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a=5;
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=5;
System.out.printf("%d", a);
```

See Formatting Numeric Print Output: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html